# Automate upload file scenario of anchor tag

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am trying to automate behavior which has multiple scenarios related to file upload with a different combination of assertions. There is an anchor tag in UI instead of an input tag that why I can't use sends keys to upload the file. I don't want to use AutoIT, Sikuli like tools as they are not compatible with remote execution on the cloud environment and add extra library liabilities.

It's an angular js application and the DOM code is

---"a href="javascript:void(0)" title="Choose File to Upload" class="btn btn-blue" ng-show="fileUploadSubmitted" id="file_input_btn" ng-click="uploadFileAttachment() "

I try to find:- 
1: Any inbuild uploading function of the angular js library so that I can execute it through the javascript executor.
2: Sikuli and AutoIt is working but that would be the last solution
3: Tried to edit tag name to input with type file in DOM followed by sendkeys but it won't work

Comment: In my experience, there's always an `INPUT` type=file element... sometimes it's just hidden. See if you can find it and post the relevant HTML along with your code attempts.

Comment: @JeffC I too agree there always a hidden element used to be in DOM, but in my case, it is not present. Seems like all the things were handled in the event function

Comment: @JeffC said `INPUT` type file button user cannot click on that in this case use javascript code for click on that button .. may be this help you...                                         `WebElement link_Home = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']"));
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();",link_Home);`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below approach.

```
Tested locally not on the server.

# get the button element
ele = driver.find_element_by_id("file_input_btn")
# add a hidden file input ( might have to change the onchange event based on the events associated to the button in above line as you don't have a form)
driver.execute_script("var x=  document.createElement('INPUT');x.setAttribute('type', 'file'); x.setAttribute('onchange','this.form.submit()');x.setAttribute('hidden', 'true'); arguments[0].appendChild(x);",ele)
# send the file path here ( this should upload the file)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys("file path should go here")
```